# Passive form + ところ? Is this different to present progressive + ところ?

Tags: grammar

この本がユニークな点は、文章の全てがメモで構成されているところです。

I am having trouble understanding the usage of ところ in this scenario. My understanding is that present progressive + ところ means 'to be in the middle of...'.

Comment: 「文章の全てがメモで構成されているところ が この本のユニークな点です。」Does this help?

Comment: This is not using ところ to describe the state of the action -- this is using ところ more literally as a noun, basically as a synonym here for 点.